# In Unity, how do I add a MeshFilter to an empty GameObject to generate a procedural model?

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject, mesh, exceptions

My code below is modeled after Unity's documentation.  When I put the script into an empty GameObject, the error I get is:

MissingComponentException: There is no 'MeshFilter' attached to the "myMesh" game object, but a script is trying to access it.

How do I add a MeshFilter (and the other necessary Components) to the empty GameObject in order to generate the model procedurally?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class myMesh : MonoBehaviour  {
    public Mesh mesh;

    void Start(){
        mesh= new Mesh();
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please remember to [check the documentation first](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) in future, or [search for your question, eg. "how to add component in Unity"](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+add+component+unity) - it's much faster than waiting for a stranger to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the AddComponent method to add a new component of your choosing:

```
var filter = AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
filter.mesh = mesh;

var renderer = AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
```